# Java multithreading mysql insert

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

My purpose: Analyze large amount of text content, approximately 90,000,000 rows stored in MySQL table. Tokenize each text, extract words and store them in table `words`.
I stored the words in a list with it's frequency:

```
public class WordEntry{
    public String word; 
    public int count = 1;
}
public void insertWord(WordEntry entry){
    for(WordEntry e:mWordList){
        if(e.word.equals(entry.word)){
            e.count++;
            return;
        }
    }
    list.add(entry);
    if(mWordList.size() > 1000){// in case of the sql cmd being too long
        flushWords(mWordList);
    }
}

public void flushWords(List<WordEntry> list){
    String sqlCmd ="insert into words(word, frequency) values %s on duplicate key update frequency = frequency+values(frequency);"
    StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();
    for(WordEntry e:list){
        values.append("("+e.word+","+e.count+"),");
    }
    values.deleteAt(values.length()-1);// remove the last comma
    sqlCmd=String.format(sqlCmd, values.toString());
    PreparedStatement ps = mConnection.prepareStatement(sqlCmd);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

as to the function `flushWords(List<WordEntry> list)`, it is inside the `class Processor implements Runnable`.
If I do it in single thread way, handling 500 rows will take about 2 seconds, so it's going to take me up to 4 days to finish all 90,000,000 rows! Of course I can run my program slowly and wait for the result, but I really want to do it faster.

So I used `ThreadPoolExecutor` to run 8 thread concurrently. It did speed up the program, but it throws mysql deadlock exception sometimes! The behavior of my program is completely **unpredictable**.

So I thought it would be better to have one single thread that does the MySQL insertion, that way I can get rid of the deadlock problem. Instead of inserting to database from inside the thread, I published the SQL command string to a `LinkedBlockingQueue<String>` and `poll(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS)` from that queue and execute them one by one, so the `flushWords` function is now:

```
public void flushWords(List<WordEntry> list){  
    ...  
    sqlCmd=String.format(sqlCmd, values.toString());
    try{
        mSqlQueue.put(sqlCmd);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class DBWorker implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            String cmd = mQueue.poll(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            PreparedStatement ps = mConnection.prepareStatement(sqlCmd);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, 8 threads push SQL command into the queue, only one thread to execute them one by one, if the limit of the queue is reached, all other threads will have to wait for available space from queue to push the SQL command in. The `DBWorker` thread slows down the entire program. If I don't limit the capacity of the queue, I'm afraid those 8 thread will fill up my entire memory space.

So, what is the best way to insert data into MySQL database with multiple thread concurrently in java?

Comment: First, the `ThreadPoolExecutor` already has a queue, you don't need to add your own. Second, I would open a different `Connection` for each thread.

Comment: I would suggest you to use Batch Inserts. https://dzone.com/articles/performant-batch-inserts-using-jdbc

Comment: @MauricePerry Each thread has its own connection, but still, deadlock happens.

Comment: @RamachandraReddy look at my SQL string build, isn't that a batch insertion?